# How to build regex for not returning empty string if none of the groups return result

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to build a regex to match timesheet hours entry where user enters his hours in the format `20h 50m`.

In this format, the user can either enter hours only `20h`, or minutes only `50m` or both hours and minutes `20h 50m`.

Sample matches

```
45m
1h
2h 45m
```

The numbers can be anything other than `20` or `50`.

I came up with this regex `((([0-9]+h)\s([0-9]+m))|([0-9]+h)|([0-9]+m)){1}`, which is long and I'm trying to reduce it.

So I tried different solution: `((\d+h)?([\s]*(\d+m))?)` https://regex101.com/r/ZEBsle/1/ .But the issue with this solution is that it matches empty strings and doesn't match patterns like `2h 45m`.

How can I modify the last regex so it can match the following formats?

```
45m
1h
2h 45m
```

Comment: Your current regex matches also `999m` - is that expected? Is `4m 4h` a valid format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To match all variations, you could use

```
\b(?:\d+h(?: \d+m)?|\d+m)\b
```

*Explanation*

- `\b` A word boundary
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\d+h` Match 1+ digits and `h`
  - `(?: \d+m)?` Optionally match a minute part
  - `|` Or
  - `\d+m` Match 1+ digits and `m`
- `)` Close group
- `\b` A word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CoOaHo/1)

If you want to match hours and minutes in that order, you might use anchors `^` and `$`

```
^(?:\d+h(?: \d+m)?|\d+m)$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HHLx7e/1)

Answer (score 1):

Here's my take at it:

```
/(?<=\b)\d+h \d+m|\d+[hm](?=\b)/g
```

[Example on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/ZEBsle/5)

```js
const str = `45m
1h
4h 35m
some text before 2h 45m and after
travelled 66miles
2m 45h this one are inversed, so treat them separately
245m`;

const times = str.match(/(?<=\b)\d+h \d+m|\d+[hm](?=\b)/g);
console.log(times);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\d+h\s\d+m|\d+h|\d+m
```

I think it will work.

Comment: `\s` is not what you want (`[ \f\n\r\t\v   -     　]`). To match exactly *Space* use ` ` . Also your code matches `23ms`